# Is there a difference between a roof and a ceiling when we talk about the inner surface?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

It seems that we use the words “ceiling” and “roof” for an upper surface of a building. However, we say “a roof” when we look from the outside, and “a ceiling” if we look from the inside.

However, H. G. Wells uses the word “roof” to describe the room's interior:

> The big doorway opened into a proportionately great hall hung with brown. **The roof was in shadow**, and the windows, partially glazed with coloured glass and partially unglazed, admitted a tempered light. The floor was made up of huge blocks of some very hard white metal, not plates nor slabs—blocks, and it was so much worn, as I judged by the going to and fro of past generations, as to be deeply channelled along the more frequented ways.
>
> *[[H. G. Wells, The Time Machine](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/35/35-h/35-h.htm#chap04)]*

Lexico does give sub-definition of “a roof” as an inner surface:

> **roof**
>
> ...
> **1**
> The structure forming the upper covering of a building or vehicle.
> *‘the rain woke him, hammering on the roof’*
>
> **1.1** The top inner surface of a covered area or space; the ceiling.
> *‘the roof of the cave fell in’*
> *‘These are special liners on the sides and sometimes the roof and back of an oven, which are treated with a material that absorbs those greasy splashes.’*
>
> *[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roof)]*

But what is the reason to call an inner surface a roof? What is the difference in this case between the words “ceiling” and “roof”?

Maybe this applies to rooms where a ceiling is also a roof, such as a room in a single-floor building or a cave?

Can H. G. Wells, calling the hall's ceiling a roof, mean that there are no more floors above the hall?

Or maybe he calls the hall's ceiling a roof because the ceiling is very large and high? Maybe a large size and height are also the reason for calling a cave's ceiling a roof?

Comment: Houses often have an angled roof and a horizontal ceiling with a space between them - that is to say that the roof and ceiling are not (necessarily) opposite sides of the same thing.

Comment: Hello, Eagle. (1) OED and Lexico are very different dictionaries. Please do not repeat the error after it has been corrected, or I will have to flag for moderator intervention. Wrong attribution is poor. (2) Obviously, although 'ceiling' (in the literal sense) is fairly precisely defined, 'roof' is more polysemous. With rooms, 'roof' may be used to mean the underside of the roof (perceived as 1-dimensional) if applicable, and 'ceiling' perhaps for a suspended ceiling. With caves and tunnels, 'roof' rather than 'ceiling' is generally used.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ceiling) gives the specific definition "the overhead inside lining of a room". This fits with the idea that a roof is the structural bit on top that keeps the rain out, and the ceiling is something below that; or in some cases there may be no lining below the roof, just as some jackets or hats are unlined, allowing you to see up into the roof.

Comment: I think "ceiling" is generally only used for rooms and other similar structures, you can't use it for other enclosed spaces. You say "roof of the mouth", you wouldn't say "ceiling of the mouth". And when talking about buildings, roof is the outside, ceiling is the inside.